# How to refactor this if statement?

Tags: c#, refactoring

is that a way to refactor the code below

```
var foot = foot.transform.position;
var hand = hand.transform.position;
if (distance > 0.5)
        {
          foot = hand;
          foot.transform.Translate(x , y  0);
        }
        else
        {
          foot.transform.Translate(x , y , 0);
         }
```

like thie below

```
var foot = foot.transform.position;
var hand = hand.transform.position;
distance > 0.5 ? {
          foot = hand,
          foot.transform.Translate(x , y  0)
                 } 
       : foot.transform.Translate(x , y  0);
```

or more clean code/.?

Comment: Do you really want to assign hand to foot?  If your variables are really descriptive of what they are then are you really replacing a foot with a hand?  And is the hand then attached to both the arm and the leg at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's no reason to have the same line of code in both the if and else, it can be moved after that logic control.
2. There's no reason to have the else, because after we remove the only line, there'd be no lines left.
3. From [Jerry's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093017/how-to-refactor-this-if-statement#comment127382241_72093017), it's better to have descriptive variable names, and make it semantically clear when doing reassignment.

```
var limb = foot.transform.position;

if (distance > 0.5)
{
    limb = hand.transform.position;
}

limb.transform.Translate(x, y, 0);
```

No need for ternary operators either.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an option:

```
var instance = distance > 0.5 ? hand.transform.position : foot.transform.position;
instance.transform.Translate(x, y, 0);
```

Comment: Or even `(distance > 0.5 ? hand : foot).transform.Translate(x, y, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

I might take this:

```
var foot = foot.transform.position;
var hand = hand.transform.position;
if (distance > 0.5)
{
  foot = hand;
  foot.transform.Translate(x , y  0);
}
else
{
  foot.transform.Translate(x , y , 0);
}
```

and refactor it to something like this:

```
var p = ( distance > 0.5 ? hand : foot ).transform.position ;
p.transform.Translate( x, y, 0 ) ;
```

Because conciseness of expression has a utility all its own.

You could even make it a "one-liner", but it just reads weird:

```
( distance > 0.5 ? hand : foot ).transform
                                .position
                                .transform
                                .Translate( x, y, 0 )
                                ;
```

The former reads better